# How to install .NET 4.0 app on Windows 8.1?

Tags: .net, installation, windows-8.1

I have a .NET 4.0 Winforms application that I'm trying to install on Windows 8.1 under InstallShield.  When the files are being copied, there are many Windows popups with the message:

```
An App on your PC needs the following Windows Feature:
.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)
```

What generates this message, and how can I eliminate it?

I'm pretty sure that all my app executable and assemblies are set for 4.0 based on the "References" and project properties.

I want to have the installation continue without a needless .NET 3.5 install since it's not needed; if I choose "Skip this installation", the application runs properly.   Even if I were to preemptively install .NET 3.5 by using DISM, it will require the user to locate the Windows 8 install CD to enable the feature.

Comment: You are tripping the "Feature on Demand" detection logic in Windows 8.  You left no breadcrumbs to guess why.  More about it [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/05/14/windows-8-and-net-framework-3-5.aspx).

Comment: That's definitely what's happening.   I'm guessing that my app is generating a false trigger for Feature on Demand.  I'll open a case with Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that several InstallShield components that contained .NET programs or assemblies had their InstallShield component ".NET Settings" set to "Local assembly", which triggered the Windows 8 [Feature On Demand](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/05/14/windows-8-and-net-framework-3-5.aspx).   Since the components didn't need to be available outside of this installation, the solution was to set them to "Not a .NET assembly".